# display array comma separated array values in table column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array

`const array =[10,20,30]`

i want to display these values in table column as 10,20,30 under column header "number".

**Note:** array elements will be dynamic.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Did you tried something, what worked, what didn't ? If you didn't tried anything, try first then tell us what you tried

Comment: I tried wit map and join and split but that did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const array =[10,20,30].join(', ')
```